# Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' with cocoapods and carthage

Tags: ios, carthage

I have cocoapods and carthage installed in my xcode project. Right after implementing Alamofire and Carthage by going through tutorials (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire, https://medium.com/@kevinle/step-by-step-guide-on-using-carthage-dependency-manager-a29c15f9a1ac), I got these build errors:

Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' and 
'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

I've tried a lot of things that were already suggested on StackOverflow but nothing is fixing it. It might be a problem with having both cocoapods and carthage? I have XCode 10.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Stupid question but... did you open .xcworkspace file?

Comment: Yes @DungeonDev